# how to calculate automatic grade and remarks in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In an HTML table, following code calculating percentage automatically through JQuery when user enters marks in 'obtained marks' column (which is an HTML text box). I am having two more columns 'grade' and 'remarks'. When user enters marks, percentage is calculated automatically, what i want is to calculate the grade and remarks automatically too.  Criteria may be above than 90 % is A+, between 80% and 90% is A, and so up to fail when student gets 30% marks. And also if grade is A+ remarks are Excellent, if grade is A, remarks are v.good and so on.

HTML code is as under:-

```
<table id = "marks" class="data-table">
    <caption class="title"></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th><strong>Sr.No.</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th>
            <th align="center"><strong>Student Name</strong></th>
            <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Obtained Marks</strong></th>
            <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Percentage</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Grade</strong></th>
            <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Remarks</strong></th>           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $stu  = $row['stu_id'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['stu_id']);
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$no.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['student_id'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value='.$row['student_id'].'>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">'.$row['student_name'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_name[]" value='.$row['student_name'].'>
                    <td>'."<input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control obtmark' type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <td>'."<input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control percentage' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <td>'."<input name='grade[]' placeholder='' class='form-control grades' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <td>'."<input name='remarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control remark' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="class[]" style="text-align: center;" value='.$row['class'].'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_date[]" value='.$TestDate.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_subject[]" align="center" value='.$SelectSubject.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_type[]" align="center" value='.$TestType.'>                             
                </tr>';
            $total += $row['stu_id'];
            $no++;      
        }
        ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery script is as under:-

```
<script>
    $('#marks').on('change', '.obtmark', function() {
        var SecondNumVal = "20";
        $mark = $(this)
        var firstNumVal = $mark.val();

        // Find the tr this control is in and the corresponding percentage field
        $pct = $mark.closest('tr').find('.percentage')
        percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100
        pct = parseInt(percentVal) + '%';
        $pct.val(pct).attr('readonly', true);
    });
$('#marks').on('change', '.percentage', function() {
    $grade = $ (this)
    var obtgrade = $grade.val();

        $studentgrade = $grade.closest('tr').find('.stugrades')
        if (obtgrade >=90 and <=100){
        calculatedgrade = "A";
        finalgrade = parseInt(calculatedgrade);
        $calculatedgrade.val(finalgrade).attr('readonly', true);

    }});
</script>
```

Can any please make amendments in jQuery to calculate next two columns ?

Comment: This is a straightforward condition. A long one, but still... Have you tried something yourself ?

Comment: @msg I have edited the code above in question which i have tried.. but its not working.

Comment: My bad, I thought it's JavaScript... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of your operations are dependent on a single value, you can perform all actions at the same time when your marks change.
Besides that, you are trying to compare an integer value with a string and mixing up your selectors.

I've simplified your html to the fields in question and only made the first condition as an example for you to finish.

```js
$('#marks').on('change', '.obtmark', function() {
  var SecondNumVal = "20";
  $mark = $(this)
  var firstNumVal = $mark.val();
  // Find the tr this control is in and the corresponding percentage field
  $row = $mark.closest('tr')
  $pct = $row.find('.percentage')
  percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100
  pct = parseInt(percentVal) + '%';
  $pct.val(pct).attr('readonly', true);

  $studentgrade = $row.find('.grades')
  $remarks = $row.find('.remark')
  if (percentVal >= 90 && percentVal <= 100) {
    calculatedgrade = "A+";
    remark = "Excellent";
  }
  $studentgrade.val(calculatedgrade).attr('readonly', true);
  $remarks.val(remark).attr('readonly', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="marks">
  <tr>
    <td><input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control obtmark' type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control percentage' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='grade[]' placeholder='' class='form-control grades' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='remarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control remark' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working fine now. You are very much helpful. Sincerest Regards!

Comment: sorry to disturb you after long time. I want to change secondNumVal to 25.. so that if the input is 25 than it will give 100%, but above code showing 125 even i ave changed secondNumVal to 25. Can you please help.

Comment: @Akhtar Not if you don't show any code, but It works for me... Watch your case, the variable is called `SecondNumVal`, not `secondNumVal` (second line on the js).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#marks').on('change', '.obtmark', function() {
  var SecondNumVal = "25";
  $mark = $(this)
  var firstNumVal = $mark.val();
  // Find the tr this control is in and the corresponding percentage field
  $row = $mark.closest('tr')
  $pct = $row.find('.percentage')
  percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100
  pct = parseInt(percentVal) + '%';
  $pct.val(pct).attr('readonly', true);

  $studentgrade = $row.find('.grades')
  $remarks = $row.find('.remark')
  if (percentVal >= 90 && percentVal <= 100) {
    calculatedgrade = "A+";
    remark = "Excellent";
  }
  $studentgrade.val(calculatedgrade).attr('readonly', true);
  $remarks.val(remark).attr('readonly', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="marks">
  <tr>
    <td><input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control obtmark' type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control percentage' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='grade[]' placeholder='' class='form-control grades' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='remarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control remark' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```